# Jenkins SVN "SSL peer shut down incorrectly" during checkout

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins, maven-release-plugin, svnkit

I have an issue running maven release plugin through Jenkins using SVN as the SCM.

When checking out large projects I get the following error, Ive searched high and low for a resolution but not come up with anything yet, it seems to be an issue with the Java SVN client that is using SVN Kit.

```
svn: E175002: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

12:37:17    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)

12:37:17    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)

12:37:17    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:777)

12:37:17    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:382)

12:37:17    ... 34 more

12:37:17 Caused by: svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on '/svn/mx/!svn/vcc/default'

12:37:17    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)

12:37:17    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:775)

12:37:17    ... 35 more

12:37:17 Caused by: svn: E175002: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

12:37:17    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:109)

12:37:17    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:526)

12:37:17    ... 35 more

12:37:17 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

12:37:17    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:408)

12:37:17    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:360)

12:37:17    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:830)

12:37:17    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:787)

12:37:17    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)

12:37:17    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)

12:37:17    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)

12:37:17    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)

12:37:17    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:75)

12:37:17    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:221)

12:37:17    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:141)

12:37:17    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:90)

12:37:17    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)

12:37:17    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)

12:37:17    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)

12:37:17    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)

12:37:17    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.XMLReader.read(XMLReader.java:39)

12:37:17    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1742)

12:37:17    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.peekChar(XMLEntityScanner.java:487)

12:37:17    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2688)

12:37:17    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)

12:37:17    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)

12:37:17    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)

12:37:17    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)

12:37:17    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)

12:37:17    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)

12:37:17    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)

12:37:17    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)

12:37:17    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:911)

12:37:17    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:876)

12:37:17    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:220)

12:37:17    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:480)
```

Jenkins allows me to retry the checkout a number of times for standard jobs so its not a problem as I just set the number of retries to 5 and it gets there in the end.

However, when using the Maven Release Plugin to perform a release, at the stage where the tag is checked out, the SVN checkout fails and the whole release fails.

My Maven release plugin config looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <providerImplementations>
            <svn>javasvn</svn>
        </providerImplementations>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

That SVN version has been selected to match the version used by Jenkins.

So my question is either:

- How to fix that error, can I set a request timeout anywhere as it seems that it is just a case of the request timing out too soon. I couldn't find anything in the docs for this.
- Can I tell Maven release plugin to retry the checkout a number of times when checking out the tag?

Comment: Are you running your builds with Java 6?

Comment: Could you please try setting your build with Java 7 and perform a new Maven Release? Maybe the problem is related to a bug with SVNKit and Java 6.

Comment: Hmmm, is that a known bug? We're using Java 6 across the board and cant upgrade to fix this bug anyway

Comment: Take a look at https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-10604

Comment: Seems to be a different error anyway

Comment: But the exception is thrown after readV3Record so maybe is related.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the error message correctly this is not an issue at the SVN client side but at the server.

Are you in control of the server that hosts your SVN repository? In that case you should probably increase the http timeout (I'm assuming you do svn over https) of the server and see if that fixes your problem.

If you are using Apache you should look for `TimeOut` in your httpd.conf file.

UPDATE:

If the situation is really that the native svn client never has any problems I'd suggest using that one instead of the `javasvn` version. If I understand it correctly the default svn implementation in maven is using the command-line client, so remove the `maven-scm-provider-svnjava` dependency and the `<svn>javasvn</svn>` config and the default should be used. (I'm no maven wizard, you might have to make other changes, and of course you probably need svn somewhere where maven can find it)

Comment: I am not in control of that server, but I should have mentioned this is ONLY a problem through Jenkins or the maven release plugin. When using a standard SVN client in unix or windows env the problem *never* occurs(Even when checking out the entire repository) so I dont believe this is an issue with the server.

Comment: I've updated my answer to suggest using native svn instead of java verseion.

Comment: I think this would fix the maven release, but in order for this to work with Jenkins, they both (maven + jenkins) need to be using the same svn client version (Which is why I added this in the first place). Any idea how to tell Jenkins to use a different svn client?
Using the Jenkins SVN plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin

Comment: As far as I know you don't need identical svn implementations in Jenkins and in maven. You do need compatible versions (not too old or too new), so if you could install a command-line version that uses the same format as jenkins that should work. This is not ideal of course, but it should work.

Comment: Alternatively you could choose to have maven also perform the 'normal' checkouts: Don't use the jenkins svn plugin but trigger your build script every x minutes and have the build script do the checkout. (Also not perfect but should work)